# Petrel - Ocean - Get well name and type

Tags: ocean, petrel

I'm getting all boreholes (Borehole Collection) from my Petrel project using the following code:

```
WellRoot wr = WellRoot.Get(PetrelProject.PrimaryProject);   
BoreholeCollection bhc = wr.BoreholeCollection;
```

I can get the borehole name (bellow code), but I'm struggling to find the type of this borehole (producer or injector) and what simulation case this borehole is comming from (I have two simulation cases in my Petrel project).

```
foreach (Borehole bh in bhc)
  PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow("Borehole name " + bh.Name);
```

Anyone could help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "what simulation case this borehole is coming from"? The case results would be coming from a simulation case, but the borehole itself is stored independently of the Case. Are you trying to determine which Borehole corresponds to certain simulation results?

Comment: Exactly! I need to find what borehole corresponds to certain simulation case. I'm using a project with two simulation cases. The first one has 4 wells and the second One two wells. The borehole list shows 6 wells, but I don't know which well is from case 1 and which is from case 2.

Answer (score 1):

This touches the display/UI domain; the access is decoupled via

```
Borehole borehole; // this is the object you have
IBoreholeSettingsFactory factory = CoreSystem.GetService<IBoreholeSettingsFactory>();
IBoreholeSettings settings = factory.GetBoreholeSettings(borehole);
WellSymbolDescription symbolDescription = settings.WellSymbol;
```

Comment: Thomas, thanks for your help. But I'm still struggling with this problem. 

Regarding the borehole type (producer/injector), I can access the WellSimbol information, but in most cases it shows (1) proposed well (default in Petrel), so I cannot identify producer and injector wells. The production/injector strategies might be an option, but each simulation case uses different keywords to set the production and injection targets.
Regarding the information about what is the simulation case of a specific borehole, I couldn't find it.